# Optimized SQL select for selecting across multiple tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following tables (testing with SQLite).

```
create table group_header (id int, minCount int, maxCount int);

create table group_items(id int, group_id int, product varchar(10), cons varchar(10));
```

The group_header has the following records:

```
id|minCount|maxCount
1|2|2
```

The group_items has the following records:

```
id|group_id|product|cons
1|1|A|optional
2|1|B|optional
3|1|C|required
4|1|D|optional
```

The SQL query should return group_header id that satisfies the following conditions:

- Input will be one or more products (e.g. 'A' and 'C')
- SQL query should check for the following criteria:

  - the `minCount` should be fulfilled for the `optional` products (i.e. `count` of `optional` items in the the input should be >= `minCount` value)
  - all the `required` products in the group_item table should exist in the input product list

Brute force way this can be done by doing the following:

```
select * from group_items where group_id = 1 and product in ('A') or cons='required';
```

and then evaluating the `minCount` and `required` separately outside SQL. Any suggestions if this can be in a more optimized way using SQL.

Comment: "`minCount` should be fulfilled".  What does that mean?

Comment: count of `optional` products should be >= `minCount`

Comment: Is the `group_id` of the `group_items` table a foreign key to `group_header.id`, or vice-versa?

Comment: yes. `group_id` in `group_items` is a FK that refers to the `group_header.id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is aggregation with a `having` clause.

```
select gh.id
from group_header gh left join
     group_items gi
     on gh.id = gi.group_id
group by gh.id
having sum( case when gi.cons = 'required' and gi.product in ('A') then 1 else 0 end) = 1 and
       sum( case when gi.cons = 'optional' then 1 else 0 end) >= gh.mincount;
```